# Can't install new linux kernel even after squeeze-backports

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm trying to upgrade my kernel version from 2.6.32 to 3.2.0.0. When I try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

I get the following error message:

```
 linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 : Depends: linux-base (>= 3~) but 2.6.32-48squeeze6 is to be installed
                              Recommends: firmware-linux-free (>= 3~) but it is not going to be installed
                              Recommends: irqbalance but it is not going to be installed
                              Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.110~) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
```

I read that the problem has to do with having two kernel versions at once, so I tried the squeeze backports option. After adding the line:

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

to my /etc/apt/sources.list, and running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -t squeeze-backports linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

I get the same error message as above. Can someone explain to me what the problem is, and how I would proceed to install the new kernel?

By the way, when I type in `sudo apt-get install -f`, I have the following message:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libfuzzy-dev : Depends: libfuzzy2 (= 2.12-1) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: Is your architecture 64 bit ?

Comment: Yeah, the architecture is 64 bit.

Comment: I'd first fix the `libfuzzy-dev` error. You might find unix.stackexchange.com a better place to ask such (non-programming) questions. What is your Debian version? If you post on unix.sx, include the output of `apt-cache policy libfuzzy2-dev libfuzzy2`.